# Cumulative sum of amortized values

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have a hard time figuring out a dax formula.
Basically, I do have a Measure called "CF_1110 MEH Bestand" (short: M1110)
What I need is a new Measure (My Goal/Target) that transforms the M1110 into something different.
I have constructed a table that manually does what I want:

[image: The Table]

Using a pivot I have pulled the M1110 showing the value per month.

The formulas spread the values in the following months.
The January value is spread over the next 12 months (1.016.972 / 12 = 84.748),
the February value is spread over the next 11 months (688.636 / 11 = 62.603),
etc.

The new Measure I need should do that and show me the sum per month.
So the Measure should result in an equivalent of that bold "Target" column to the right.

My current solution: I load this handcrafted Table into the Data Modell via query and those have it in the data model. The issue: That solution si not really flexible or robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through each month up until the current one summing the measure distributed across the future months.

```
Target =
CALCULATE (
    SUMX ( Table1, [CF_1110 MEH Bestand] / ( 13 - Table1[Month] ) ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( Table1[Month] ), Table1[Month] <= MAX ( Table1[Month] ) )
)
```

Comment: If I want to cumulate this measure again. How do I proceed? Using  Calculate(Sumx...Filter(... <= MAX does not work.